# java.sql.SQLDataException: invalid month when getting data from Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, sqlexception

I've been with this exception all day and now I'm going crazy, I cannot find what's wrong in my code. I've checked and rechecked the method but I wasn't able to find a solition, I have checked and rechecked the date formats and they are all fine... Why is this sending the `month invalid`exception. The full stacktrace is the following, I also had found that the program throws that exception when calling `ResultSet.next()` method.

```
feb 27, 2012 4:03:38 PM mx.gob.sagarpa.utilidades.Database generarReporteArchivos
SEVERE: null
java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01843: not a valid month

        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:445)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:879)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:450)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:193)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.fetch(T4CStatement.java:1108)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.close_or_fetch_from_next(OracleResultSetImpl.java:373)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.next(OracleResultSetImpl.java:
277)
        at mx.gob.sagarpa.utilidades.Database.generarReporteArchivos(Database.ja
va:160)
        at mx.gob.sagarpa.beans.TableBean.generarReportes(TableBean.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:262)
        at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:2
78)
        at org.ajax4jsf.component.behavior.MethodExpressionAjaxBehaviorListener.
processAjaxBehavior(MethodExpressionAjaxBehaviorListener.java:71)
        at javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent.processListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent
.java:113)
        at javax.faces.component.behavior.BehaviorBase.broadcast(BehaviorBase.ja
va:106)
        at org.ajax4jsf.component.behavior.AjaxBehavior.broadcast(AjaxBehavior.j
ava:291)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:
760)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)

        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1
259)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicat
ionPhase.java:81)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)

        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:304)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperV
alve.java:224)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextV
alve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(Authentica
torBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.j
ava:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.j
ava:100)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:
929)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineVal
ve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.jav
a:405)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp
11Processor.java:964)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(
AbstractProtocol.java:515)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoin
t.java:1824)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

**CODE**

```
public List<RegistroReporteArchivo> generarReporteArchivos(
        int idUsuario, String nombreArchivo,
        String fechaInicio, String fechaFin) {
    CallableStatement cs;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    List<RegistroReporteArchivo> list = new ArrayList<RegistroReporteArchivo>();
    try {
        connect();
        cs = connection.prepareCall("{call getreportearchivo(?,?,?,?,?)}");
        cs.setInt(1, idUsuario);
        cs.setString(2, nombreArchivo);
        cs.setString(3, fechaInicio);
        cs.setString(4, fechaFin);
        cs.registerOutParameter(5, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
        cs.execute();
        rs = (ResultSet) cs.getObject(5); 
        while (rs.next()) {  //The exception marks this line as the responsible !!
            list.add(new RegistroReporteArchivo(rs.getString(1),
                    rs.getInt(2), rs.getInt(3), rs.getInt(4),
                    rs.getInt(5)));
        }
        disconnect();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Database.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: You may want to provide your procedure definition.

Comment: Are u passing a date as a string?

Comment: quite possibly youre passing the date as an invalid string format.

Comment: Why are not you setting dates by cs.setDate() ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the signature of the `getreportearchivo` procedure?  Are one or more of the parameters declared to be a `DATE`?  If so, you should really be calling `setDate` rather than `setString`.

If all the parameters to the procedure are, in fact, `VARCHAR2` parameters, do you convert the strings to dates in the procedure?  If so, the format mask specified in the `TO_DATE` function doesn't appear to match the string that is being passed in.

Comment: Yes in fact they are all varchar2. I've checked again the procedure and there was an `ORDER BY` clause that was like `ORDER BY to_date(fechaCarga)` and I wasn't formatting the date to the format I'm using, so just with `ORDER BY to_date(fechaCarga,'DD/MM/YYYY)` the problem was solved. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Run the following sql statement and check your NLS_DATE_FORMAT.

```
select * from nls_session_parameters;
```

The output might look like

```
SQL> select * from nls_session_parameters;

PARAMETER                      VALUE
------------------------------ ----------------------------------------
NLS_LANGUAGE                   ENGLISH
NLS_TERRITORY                  UNITED KINGDOM
NLS_CURRENCY                   £
NLS_ISO_CURRENCY               UNITED KINGDOM
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS         .,
NLS_CALENDAR                   GREGORIAN
**NLS_DATE_FORMAT                DD-MON-RR**
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE              ENGLISH
NLS_SORT                       BINARY
NLS_TIME_FORMAT                HH24.MI.SSXFF
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT           DD-MON-RR HH24.MI.SSXFF
NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT             HH24.MI.SSXFF TZR
NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT        DD-MON-RR HH24.MI.SSXFF TZR
NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY              €
NLS_COMP                       BINARY
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS           BYTE
NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP            FALSE

17 rows selected.
```

Check the format of the date that you are passing to the procedure. It might solve the problem.